# Image next to text?

Tags: java, android, xml, algorithm, text

**TL;DR: Using the simple `android:drawableLeft` functionality on a Textview leads to a crash**

The `TextView` is one of Android's most basic visual elements. Then why is it that it's most basic functionality is not working?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft

My code is simple—it's a custom dialog using an image next to a `TextView`:

```
<TextView
        android:text="Text next to check mark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_check_circle_white_24dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"/>
```

**The code provides stunning results on the visual editor:**

[image]

But when the program is actually executed, the simple `android:drawableLeft` functionality crashes the app:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class TextView
```

[Full stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/RuchirB/e7a3891b455b56f60f1e7d9d36ee31e6)

---

*I try opening the dialog like so:*

```
dialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert );
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.premium_dialog);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

dialog.getWindow().setLayout((int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 0.90), (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * 0.90));

dialog.show();
```

Why is it that such basic functionality is the cause of an `InflateException`? (I know it is the `drawableLeft` function that is causing the issue, because when I remove the TextView, the error is gone)

Comment: From your full stack trace where have you used `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File **res/drawable/abc_dialog_material_background.xml** from color state list resource ID #0x7f020011`

Comment: You can't use `vectordrwable` directly in `Textview` with lower API. Create CustomTextview to give support to vector in Lower API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one on setContentView

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.premium_dialog, null);
dialog.setContentView(promptView);
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a CustomTextView for VectorDrawable in Lower API.

Initilize your Attribute of Custom Textview as following:

```
private void initAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray attributeArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.CustomTextView);
            //for font
            String fontName = attributeArray.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_font);

            try {
                if (fontName != null) {
                    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
                    setTypeface(myTypeface);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Drawable drawableLeft = null;
            Drawable drawableRight = null;
            Drawable drawableBottom = null;
            Drawable drawableTop = null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                drawableLeft = attributeArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableLeftCompat);
                drawableRight = attributeArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableRightCompat);
                drawableBottom = attributeArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableBottomCompat);
                drawableTop = attributeArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableTopCompat);
            } else {
                final int drawableLeftId = attributeArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableLeftCompat, -1);
                final int drawableRightId = attributeArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableRightCompat, -1);
                final int drawableBottomId = attributeArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableBottomCompat, -1);
                final int drawableTopId = attributeArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableTopCompat, -1);

                if (drawableLeftId != -1)
                    drawableLeft = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableLeftId);
                if (drawableRightId != -1)
                    drawableRight = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableRightId);
                if (drawableBottomId != -1)
                    drawableBottom = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableBottomId);
                if (drawableTopId != -1)
                    drawableTop = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableTopId);
            }
            setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableLeft, drawableTop, drawableRight, drawableBottom);
            attributeArray.recycle();
        }
    }
```

Your custom Styleable for same.

```
<attr name="drawableLeftCompat" format="reference" />
    <attr name="drawableRightCompat" format="reference" />
    <attr name="drawableTopCompat" format="reference" />
    <attr name="drawableBottomCompat" format="reference" />

    <declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
        <attr name="font" format="string" />
        <attr name="drawableLeftCompat" />
        <attr name="drawableRightCompat" />
        <attr name="drawableTopCompat" />
        <attr name="drawableBottomCompat" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

Comment: Why? I am just dealing with simple .png from (https://material.io/icons/#ic_check_circle), not vectors! Why must I implement this method, if the basic functionality is to just use `drawableLeft`?

Comment: @Ruchir Banronia If your `drawableLeft` is not Vector _(Which is more preffered and scalable)_ there is no need to create custom Textview to access .png file. But from your stackTrace it shows you are trying to acces vector drawble.

Comment: That is why I am so confused. I'm using the .png file from here: https://material.io/icons/#ic_check_circle. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`android:drawableLeft` (and top/right/bottom) can't use vector drawables on older API levels. Either use a .png drawable or use a LinearLayout with an ImageView next to your TextView.

Comment: It is a PNG, I downloaded the check mark from https://material.io/icons/#ic_check_circle